# Google Tag Manager ID rewriting from "GTM-XXXXXXX" to "G&reg;-XXXXXXX"

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I've installed a google tag manager snippet in the head of a website, and no matter what method I use (Google Site Kit, manually hard coding into header.php, or adding it to a custom field that displays in the head of the site) when it renders on the front end it is rewriting the beginning of the ID as "G&reg-".

I initially disabled plugins, inspected code, etc and there was no change.

So I then installed a copy of the same site on another hosting platform and there is no issue, it displays as "GTM-".  I've contacted the hosting company where the issue is occuring and they say there is nothing on the server side that would cause this and keep suggesting that I've made a typo.

Comment: It's incredibly hard to pin this down since you give so little information of what you're doing. My first suspicion is that you copy the tag from somewhere where it was already "mistranslated" from "GTM" to "G™" for some weird reason.

Comment: It's not already mistranslated, if that were the case then it would display mistranslated on both hosting platforms.  As I stated, I copy the same snippet into the same site on two different hosting platforms and one renders it incorrectly when viewed in dev console in the browser.   The assumption that it is already mistranslated would also assume that when the Google Site Kit plugin places the tag that Google Site Kit is mistranslating it.  That's not the case either.

Comment: I've tested 3 ways of placing the snippet (as I explained) in the page and in all three cases on one hosting platform it displays correctly, and on the other it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the snippet as it appears on your site and I can check for you? When you mention you tried using Site Kit, the plugin will insert a Google Analytics snippet on a users site as per [this guide](https://sitekit.withgoogle.com/documentation/using-site-kit/site-kit-modules-and-your-sites-source-code/).

The G- prefix (as per that guide) can related to your Google Analytics 4 measurement ID. Site Kit also uses the new Google tag so it's also possible to encounter a GT- prefix (see [this guide](https://sitekit.withgoogle.com/documentation/using-site-kit/the-google-tag/)).

Once I can see your snippet I can check whether all looks good. You can also use the [tagassistant.google.com](https://tagassistant.google.com) service if you're unsure whether any tags are firing on your site, including Analytics tags.